# how to get the remaining contents of a split?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a string:

```
var myFilename = "342134_My_Awesome_File.zip
```

I would like to extract just: `My_Awesome_File.zip`.

I am attempting to do this with the following:

```
var removedPrependedTieBreaker = myFilename.Split('_').Skip(1);
```

However, that will yield an `IEnumerable<string>`.

How do we do a `split` on underscore, and get the rest of the contents?

Comment: `string.Join('_', removedPrependedTieBreaker)`

Comment: No need to split (destroy) and then re-join (recreate) the most parts of the string again... and Joe Sewell wrote the answer :-)

Comment: @elgonzo monkey's solution is more elegent actually

Comment: How is that more elegant?

Comment: Elegance is subjective, the involved cost not so much ;-)

Comment: Elegance is indeed in the eye of the beholder, hence why mine is a comment. Personally, I like @Joe's solution the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I like Joe Sewell's answer, I just thought I'd give you another way (besides `string.Join`, as mentioned in the question comments) to make your own approach work:

```
var removedPrependedTieBreaker = myFilename.Split('_').Skip(1).Aggregate((current, next) => $"{current}_{next}");
```

This will take the `IEnumerable<string>` that you made and recompose the pieces as a `string` with `_` as a delimiter.

Comment: This is waaaay too complicated and needlessly slow.

Comment: I would argue that, given the premise of providing a solution to the original approach, it's only complicated if you lack understanding of LINQ's `Aggregate` method, and it's only slow if you're either working on a very large set of data, or if you're on a very resource limited system. I do, however, prefer the substring approach provided by Joe Sewell, as implied by my answer.

Comment: It's complicated regardless whether or not you understand `Aggregate` or not. The fact it's such a simple problem but you are using this over-engineered method is the reason it is complicated. Linq is a wonderful too but too many people use it as a hammer for everything that looks like a nail.

Comment: Let's disagree on how complicated `Aggregate` is. If you do want to talk about overcomplicating things, how come in your answer you didn't just stick with `myFilename.Split(new[] { '_' }, 2)`? `StringSplitOptions.None` is default behavior for this overload. The few cycles saved by calling the method with all three parameters is hardly noticable.

Comment: Did I say `Aggregate` was complicated? I was saying it's far more complicated than the simple solution. As for my answer, yes, I could remove that, but it doesn't make it *simpler*.

Comment: I did write that a premise for my answer was building on what was already done. Besides `string.Join()`, it can't be much simpler than this, as I see it. Regarding your explicitly setting something to the default value, would you also say that using `Split()` is equal in simplicity to using `Split(new char[0], int.MaxValue, StringSplitOptions.None)`?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use a different overload of split that takes the count:

```
var parts = myFilename.Split(new[] { '_' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
var interestingData = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

You could recombine the remaining parts with [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___). But maybe it would be better to avoid splitting and just take a substring:

```
myFilename.Substring(myFilename.IndexOf('_') + 1)
```

Comment: Does the `.IndexOf()` not grab the index of all the `_` characters?

Comment: @Symon: No, just the first, unless you specify a start index.